# Fetching api returns Array of Arrays instead Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, axios, fetch

I am a Front end developer and I am working on a project which requires CRUD operations, I came to the point in which I have to fetch data from an API. I tested the API in Postman and Arc, the data is coming out fine as it should (Array of objects), but when I fetch in the app either with Axios or with Fetch the data I get is, Array of Arrays, this never happened and I could use the help.

```
axios
.get(
  "***$format=json",
  { withCredentials: "true" }
)
.then((data) => {
  console.log(data, "data");
})
.catch((err) => console.log(err, "err"));
```

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTrIL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJvOw.png)

Comment: Please show an example of the actual data returned perhaps and if possible the postman request?

Comment: data.data.d.results is the array you want, why it comes this way is about your service end point.

Comment: okay, there you have the data

Comment: `data` is the axios return value which is an object that contains the property `data`. So `data.data` is actually the response from your server. The response from your server is an object that contains the property `d` whose value is an object that contains the property `results` which is an array.

Comment: So what I have understood, is that the problem is on the Backend even though in Postman data is returned just fine?

Comment: there is actually no problem here, you dont get array in array, just one array: data.data.d.results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen the consol log and it seems that it is an Array of Object only but the length of the array is 1823 so chrome changed the way of showing, it just made groups of 100 arrays so if you just try to iterate through the response using **.map** method then you will find out that actually, it is an array of object

Comment: I have no idea how this actually worked even though I tried looping and writing out data a million times. Anyways, thank you

Answer (score 0):

axios
.get(
"***$format=json",
{ withCredentials: "true" }
).then((data) => {
console.log(data.d.results);
}).catch((err) => console.log(err, "err"));

Comment: please provide more information, and indent your code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if the response can be set from the backend, or if the backend does send the response in the form of an array of objects, you can convert to an array of array like this:

```
const output = input.map((obj) => Object.keys(obj).map((key) => obj[key]));
```